# nodejs editing a date - unexpected behavior?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime

I am editing a date in nodejs like so:

[image]

But instead of adding x hours it moves the date several days in future.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas what causes this?

Comment: Try replacing `setUTCHours` with just `setHours`, could be the timezone difference ?

Comment: Sadly it does not seem to be so simple ;) It changes the time because of the timezone, but there's still several days of difference between dates after changing the hour parameter.

Comment: So if you do `occurence.start.setHours(occurence.start.getHours() + 5) `you're still adding several days? I don't really see how that's possible

Comment: Exactly my thoughts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
occurence.start.setHours(occurence.start.getHours() + parseInt(event.rule.schedule.parameter))
```

and see if it works..

Comment: Whoa. It would seem it did the trick, I'll have to test with seconds,minutes, days, months and years though. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Qweick, to answer your question why it works... because event.rule.schedule.parameter is String.  So if getHours() returns 12 and event.rule.schedule.parameter='3', instead of 12+3=15, the value becomes 123.  That's why it could be days instead of hours.